# Quotient algebras isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

Are these algebras isomorphic?

1) $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^n-y)$ and $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x-y^m)$
2) $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2-y^2)$ and $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/((x-y)^2)$

1) I was given advice to use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem). Well, as i understand a typical element of algebra like $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x-y^m)$ looks like $P = kI + r$, where $P, k, r$ are some polynomials, $I = x - y^m$ and degree($r$) < degree($I$). So due to little Bézout's theorem we get $r = P(a)$ and $I = x-a=x-y^m$, so $a=y^m$. I don't see any ways to make it useful. Was it wrond way?

2) I'm not sure about this, but the first one does have zero divisors and the second one doesn't. How can i check it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Use the homomorphism $f:\mathbb{C}[x,y]\to \mathbb{C}[x]$ with $f(x)=x, f(y)=x^n$ and thus show that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^n-y)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[x]$ and similarly, the second one is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[y]$. So, both are isomorphic.
2) The second one has nilpotents, since $x-y\neq 0$ but its square is, while the first has none. So, they are not isomorphic.